# Converting a python script to a web application

Tags: python

I have a python script written up and the output of this script is a list . Right now I need to get it online and make it accesible to others. I looked at Django , but then I realised that it may be kind of hard to create the UI. Is there any simple way to create a UI in Django and map it to an existing python script. Right now I am not using sql and things like that. Or is there a simpler way by which I can proceed?

Comment: Consider web.py. You will get started immediately.

Comment: Try a microframework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Flask or bottle would be a good starting point.

Comment: You can go through this [web.py tutorial](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial) to get started in 15min. forget the UI part and just output your list as string.

Comment: There is also CherryPy you might be interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [web.py](http://webpy.org/).

Django pays off if you develop a large app; yours is not.

Probably all you need is two pages: one with an input form, and another with results. As long as your input is text, you should have little trouble taking input from a POST handler and passing it as is to your script.

Both microframeworks have tutorials: here's [web.py's](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial), and [Flask's](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is right on the home page. Should get you started very quickly.